# How to save an HTML document in one file on Windows?

Tags: pdf, html, mht

I wrote a product manual using HTML that includes images and I wanted to save it in one file that I could send for customers for viewing. Someone suggested converting it to a PDF but the problem is that although HTML links/bookmarks work in PDFs they are not easy to follow (Adobe reader doesn't have Back and Forward buttons for links) and it's not easy to read. Then someone suggested opening my HTML in IE and saving it as .mht file. I did so and the page looks great, except one "small" fact that all internal links/bookmarks don't work. For some stupid reason they all have absolute URLs that obviously don't work on another computer.

So any suggestions how to save HTML for viewing in one file (offline)?

Comment: Have you ruled out publishing the HTML on a web-server? If necessary you could create user-ids and passwords for each customer.

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea. I was still thinking of providing some offline method in case a person can't access the web.

Answer (score 0):

Possible options include

Convert the HTML and associated files to an executable. I asked Google about "html to exe" and saw some useful looking results.

Convert the HTML to a common word-processing format. I'd guess that RTF is readable on a wide range of platforms. If (as most business people assume) your customers can read Microsoft Word documents, you could try that format or the more open OpenDocument format. Again, Google is a useful recource

Answer (score 0):

Windows only solution:

1. Create the batch file `manual.bat` consisting of following line:

   ```
   start manual.html
   ```
2. Download and install [Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?pid=b2e).
3. Open Bat To Exe Converter and apply the following settings:

   ```
   Batch file: manual.bat
   Save As:    manual.exe
   Options:
       Visibility:        Invisible application
       Temporary files:   Delete at exit
       Working directory: Temporary directory
   Include:
       manual.html
       image1.png
       image2.png
       .
       .
       .
   ```
4. (optional) Fill the tab `Versioninformations` with **meaningful** descriptions and an icon, so your manual doesn't look like a virus.
5. Click `Compile`.